# An non-decomposable FD group with infinitely many conjugacy class of a fixed order

Tags: group-theory

[Before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838603/fc-groups-with-infinite-derived-subgroup-which-are-not-constructed-by-direct-pro), I asked about an FC (finite conjugacy group) which is not FD (with an infinite derived subgroup) and non-decomposable as a direct product $A \times B$ for two non-trivial subgroups $A$ and $B$. Here I have two more questions:

1. Is there an infinite group $G$ with a finite derived subgroup (FD) which is not decomposable as a direct product $A \times B$ for two non-trivial subgroups?
2. In particular, can we find a non-decomposable infinite FD group $G$ with a constant $d\geq 1$ so that the set $\{ a \in G^\#: |a|\neq d\}$ is finite. (Here $G^\#$ denotes the set of all conjugacy classes of $G$).

Comment: I should mention that since $G$ is FD, it is automatically FC and therefore $|a|$ for every $a \in G^\#$ is a finite number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an infinite extraspecial $p$-group, for $p$ prime, with presentation
$$\langle a_i,b_i,z\ (i \in {\mathbb Z}) \mid [a_i,b_i]=z, a_i^p=b_i^p=[z,a_i]=[z,b_i]=[a_i,a_j]=[b_i,b_j]=[a_i,b_j]=1  (\forall i\ne j \in {\mathbb Z}) \rangle.$$

Its derived group is $\langle z \rangle$, which is also the centre of $G$ and has order $p$, and all noncentral conjugacy classes have order $p$.

Comment: Does an infinite extraspecial $p$-group have any (infinite) abelian subgroup of finite index?

Comment: Sorry, I missed out afew commuting relations . I've put them in now. There are no abelian subgroups of finite index. $\langle z, a_i \ (i \in {\mathbb Z} )\rangle$ is a maximal abelian subgroup, and it has infintie index.